# More concise word of phrase for "to turn into a process"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a more concise way of describing the process of turning something into a process.

Often we have tacit knowledge about things we do frequently, sometimes called muscle memory.

What do you call the thoughtful process of turning that into a process or procedure–into something step by step and detailed?

Comment: do you need a verb or noun? Do you mean something like a process or set of rules to be followed in a procedure? Or something that divides a process into steps?

Comment: A verb would be great.  I'm looking for the action of turning something into a process.

Comment: Automate? Program?

Comment: I heard you liked processes…

Comment: Processize seems the obvious way to verbize this noun.

Comment: procedurize?  you probably should say procedure and not process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mechanise](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Mechanise): may convey the idea I think

> mechanise - make monotonous; make automatic or routine; "If your work becomes too mechanized, change jobs!"

Comment: Mechanize is great.  I went with this.

Answer (score 4):

**routinize**

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/routinize

> 1. to develop into a regular procedure.
> 2. to reduce to a customary procedure:

**systematize**

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/systematize

> to arrange in or according to a system; reduce to a system; make systematic.

Answer (score 4):

Formalize is the word I typically use when, for example, taking an informally followed process or practice and putting it in to some form others can use.

> formalize - give (something) a definite structure or shape

Answer (score 2):

To Codify or to encode

> codify - arrange according to a plan or system.
>   "this would codify existing intergovernmental cooperation on drugs"

Alternatively to systematize.

> systematize - arrange according to an organized system; make systematic.
>   "Galen set about systematizing medical thought"

Comment: The answer would be more useful if you provided a dictionary definition and a link to your source.

Answer (score -2):

Processize.  Just make it up.  Thats how every word in the English language became a word.  Someone just made it up and it became accepted.

Comment: This word is also coined by Sahil Lavingia in his book The Minimalist Entrepreneur.

Comment: This candidate obviously hasn't been accepted. And ELU focuses on standard usages.

Answer (score -2):

Processtize is a useful verb. To me, it’s more intuitive than Processize.
If you rework the sentence, the suggestion above to “Routinize a an unstructured process” is a good one.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Other than compounds like "crosstalk" or even "bremsstrahlung", you would be hard pressed to find "sst" in English words. As a result, your suggestion looks unnatural to me.

Comment: Sorry, David. ELU focuses on standard usages. Candidates without a realistic currency do not constitute acceptable answers.